# Jhipster table creation

Tags: jhipster

I deleted jhi_user table and now when I run mvn command I get this error
"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'jhi_user'"
I thought that it will be regenerated but it's not the case.
Any idea ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you delete the “databasechangelog” and “databasechangeloglock” tables and re-run your app, Liquibase will re-create **all** your tables. You'll lost your data though.

Comment: Strange, anyway you can then delete the database entirely